# Datatable implements IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, datatable, ienumerable

In picture :

[image]

How does `AsEnumerable` Methods Knows that the type should be `DataRow` ?

I've searched in Reflector and `Datatable` does **Not** implement IEnumerable..

And the AsEnumerable code is:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> AsEnumerable<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    return source;
}
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong `AsEnumerable` method - you're calling [`DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx). rather than [`Enumerable.AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx).

Comment: the Reflector didnt show it to me . I had to import this strange dll inorder to see it :( thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using dotnet core and having the same issue, you need to add "System.Data.DataTableExtensions" in Nuget